# Mutable borrow in a getter not living long enough

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```
pub type Data = i32;

pub struct Foo {
    data: Data,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn data_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Data {
        &mut self.data
    }
}

pub struct Context {
    data: Data,
    foos: Vec<Foo>,
}

impl Context {
    pub fn broken(&mut self) -> &mut Data {
        // What are the lifetimes here that make this version not work?
        &mut self.foos.first_mut().unwrap().data_mut()
    }

    pub fn working(&mut self) -> &mut Data {
        &mut self.foos.first_mut().unwrap().data
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=991b2b113bfcaf7be126cc3ef7ce1ddd&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018))

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:21:14
   |
21 |         &mut self.foos.first_mut().unwrap().data_mut()
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
22 |     }
   |     - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 19:5...
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 | /     pub fn broken(&mut self) -> &mut Data {
20 | |         // What are the lifetimes here that make this version not work?
21 | |         &mut self.foos.first_mut().unwrap().data_mut()
22 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

I didn't want to have the `data` field public, so I tried to use a getter. I know getters are not working well in Rust, and properly encapsulated collection shouldn't have a mutable `get`, but this is some code I'm porting from a different language, so I'm not performing any refactoring at the moment (just porting and covering with tests). What's the lifetime issue there?

Comment: I find the question interesting, but I think that the code can be minimized.

Comment: @Boiethios Minimal reproduction: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3957938b4cd94f640624bfcc8adfc2ad&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018 I also thought that NLL would fix this code.

Comment: I can't tell if it applies to your original larger code, but the issue in your playground samples is that you don't need the `&mut`, since `data_mut` already returns a `&mut Data`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b885337f7afd99e59ecb1bf62aaf2b3c&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018

Comment: Oh my. *Facepalm*. Yes, that worked. I was getting used to prefix field references with `&mut `, and prefixed the getter returns as well. Waiting to mark your answer as **the** answer

Comment: So, as I understand now, the getter was returning a proper reference up to the caller. Prefixing the result with `&mut` caused that result to become a temporary, and the code was attempting to return a reference to this temporary, which was technically correct, because of the coercion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
pub fn broken(&mut self) -> &mut Data {
    &mut self.foos.first_mut().unwrap().data_mut()
}
```

the core issue is that the return type of `data_mut()` is already a `&mut Data` value, so you're essentially creating a `&mut &mut Data`, though that will collapse. The simplest fix in your case is to drop the `&mut` entirely

```
pub fn broken(&mut self) -> &mut Data {
    self.foos.first_mut().unwrap().data_mut()
}
```

It would seem that by adding the `&mut` you're causing the borrow checker to create a temporary location and then take a reference to that location.